# Excel duplicate sheet from list of names

Tags: excel, vba

I have large workbook, with a selections of sheets which I need copy/duplicate  to a new sheet with name as below: It's to generate a big specifications data sets with just few elements changed

```
     Colum A     Colum B
1    SheetName   CopyName
2    Sheet4      Spec_ABC
3    Sheet4      Spec_BCD
4    Sheet5      Spec_123
5    Sheet5      Spec_456
6    Sheet9      Spec_Any
7    ShettA      Spec_More

workbooks  Master / Sheet4 / Sheet5 / Sheet9 / SheetA etc...
```

The code below I found will do a copy for the names from  Sheet(2)
I am unsure how to change the (2) to reflect the SheetName. ie colum A data.

So in essence Copy SheetName to Copy to CopyName. The CopyNames have no duplicate names, so error checking is not needed.

```
Sub AutoAddSheet()
Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range
Set MyRange = Sheets("Master").Range("B2")
Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))

For Each MyCell In MyRange
Sheets(2).Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'Create a new worksheet as a copy of Sheet number
Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value 'Renames the new worksheets
Next MyCell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close, I'd do it SLIGHTLY differently, but given your code as a base, here's something that should do the trick:

```
Sub AutoAddSheet()
    Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range
    Set MyRange = Sheets("Master").Range("A2")
    Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))

    For Each MyCell In MyRange
        Sheets(MyCell.Value).Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'Create a new worksheet as a copy of Sheet number
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Offset(0, 1).Value 'Renames the new worksheets
    Next MyCell
End Sub
```

Basically, you wanted to replace `Sheets(2)` with `Sheets(<sheet name>)`
And what I did was loop down Column A (`Set MyRange = Sheets("Master").Range("A2")`) - Which had the sheet names and then set the name using the `MyCell.Offset(0, 1)` which is saying *Get the value from the corresponding B column*

Hope this makes sense!

Comment: Hi and thanks for super answer The Offset was the magic, you are super *, thanks for saving me needless copy / paste.

Comment: So glad it worked, @user2671620, and welcome to S.O. - As a new user, remember to mark the solution as having worked for you... It'll increase your rankings and show other people searching for a similar issue that this was what helped you.